# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Failed to load receiver assembly

Tags: visual-studio

I get frequently this error when i try to update my solution using VS deployment  method in  the same environment , at first itry with  recycling pool , retract solution from GAC and other  cleaning steps , so  some time they work but most of time i should workaround using PS but other  a simple solution was available just i should **re-signing** my solution **(new key.snk)**

```
Error   5   Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Failed to load receiver assembly "SharePointSolution.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6a659263ab23f6f5" for feature "SharePointSolution.Core_ConfigBuilder" (ID: b72d32e2-a96d-4960-b372-5278d9daa070).: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SharePointSolution.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6a659263ab23f6f5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'SharePointSolution.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6a659263ab23f6f5'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\vssphost5.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = SharePointSolution.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6a659263ab23f6f5
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/Extensions/Microsoft/SharePoint/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\VstspCache12120
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\vssphost5.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: SharePointSolution.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6a659263ab23f6f5
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.

        0   0   SharePointSolution.Core
```

Answer (score 3):

I get frequently this error when i try to update my solution using VS deployment  method in  the same environment , at first itry with  recycling pool , retract solution from GAC and other  cleaning steps , so  some time they work but most of time i should workaround using PS but other  a simple solution was available just i should **re-signing** my solution **(new key.snk)**